# Is there a way to randomize the jsonPath array number in get[] myJson?

Tags: json, karate

I have a list of values that I can use for the title field in my json request. I would like to store a function in the common.feature file which randomizes the title value when a scenario is executed.

I have attempted using the random number function provided on the commonly needed utilities tab on the readme. I have generated a random number successfully, the next step would be using that randomly gernerated number within the jsonpath line in order to retrieve a value from my data list which is in json.

````
    * def myJson =
"""
{
  "title" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "enum" : [
                  "MR",
                  "MRS",
                  "MS",
                  "MISS"
                  [...]
               ]
            }
}
"""

    * def randomNumber = random(3)
    * def title = get[0] myJson.title.enum


    * print title```

The code above works but I would like to randomize the number within the get[0]. How is this possible in Karate?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want, but can't you just replace 0 by randomNumber in `get[randomNumber] myJson.title.enum` ?

Comment: yep. and for another example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/random-jsonpath.feature - you can always use `List.get(index)` once you have a JSON array instead of JsonPath